# Can't retrieve data from firestore - getting an error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I've started to receive an error while reading data from the backend (firestore). I have to mention that till a week ago, everything run just fine. I'm running my files locally (not hosted). But when I host my app, everything runs smooth. The app is very simple, a web App which retrieves data from the firestore and presents it to the user.
I've also noticed that it happens with chrome. On IE and Firefox it works good.

this is what I get

Failed to load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fempl-1: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.